# How to test if a file exists in the Windows virtual store

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to test if a file exists in the Virtual Store on my Windows 8.1 PC.  If I go to Windows explorer, I can see it but when I use the following code, it is treating it as if the file does not exist.

```
Dim virtualFilePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Local\VirtualStore\Windows\fsp.bin")

If System.IO.File.Exists(virtualFilePath) Then
  Console.WriteLine("File exists in the virtual store")
End If
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**
My error.  I got the file path to the virtual store wrong by accidently including an extra 'local' directory.  The following code works:

```
Dim virtualFilePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "VirtualStore\Windows\fsp.bin")
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is you are pointing to the wrong directory, since because

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)'<---- points to the 
'<--- C:\Users\me\AppData\Local
```

when you combine it with `"Local\VirtualStore\Windows\fsp.bin"` will lead to an unknown directory because it results in a path `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\fsp.bin` As you said an additional local is occur so you need to eliminate this, try the code as below

```
Dim virtualFilePath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData).ToString & "\VirtualStore\Windows\fsp.bin"
If System.IO.File.Exists(virtualFilePath) Then
   Console.WriteLine("File exists in the virtual store")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Neethu.  I got there soon after posting the question.  Lesson learned - test more before posting question.  I had in my head that the virtual store was adding a layer of complication which is clearly wasn't.

Comment: anyway happy to help you. keep posting when you struggle with error/s

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the file path set to the virtual store was incorrect.  After removing the extra 'local' directory, the above code does correctly indicate that the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the FileInfo class, it works perfetly.

```
    Dim f As New IO.FileInfo(Path)

    If f.Exists Then
        'do something
    End If
```